# How can we format CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to be in "M/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

How to get snowflake sql equivalent for sql server version of this SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt', 'en-US')?

Comment: Please, check the documentation first: [```TO_VARCHAR( <date_or_time_expr> [, '<format>' ] )```](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html)

Comment: Hi Miyo ... welcome to your first post ... hopefully everyone with play nice since it's your first time here :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basics ...

```
SELECT to_char (current_timestamp(), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') i
```

[image]

However you should think about the TimeZone ... [here's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz) a good place to start in the docs.

This can be done via session settings or in the ddl e.g.

```
alter session set timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
```